# Use of memcached when Hibernate already present and uses caching

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, redis, memcached

I wanted to know since there is hibernate ORM present in the market with caching feature included that reduces the DB load in applications, what can be the usability for external caching systems like Redis/Memcached since they also provide caching mechanism.

Since our objects are already cached using hibernate in the application, what can be the usability for external caching systems. How would they be of any help in the application performance?

Should we store our class objects in memcached/redis also when hibernate already holds them in memory or should memcached be used only for storing list results which normally do not change and not the objects which can be fetched from hibernate cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate ORM provides two levels of caching

-**First Level cache**: In-process cache associated with every session object, limited to session level i.e. each session has its own first level cache.

-**2nd level cache**: Pluggable cache that needs to be configured. It is session factory level cache i.e. shared between multiple session.

Caching solutions like memcached/redis or [Tayzgrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/) for example, provide 2nd level caching providers for hibernate which can be configured in hibernate application. Using such cache provider you can incorporate distributed caching features in hibernate application, like cache can be shared between multiple sessions as well as multiple applications using the same database.

Keep in mind that when using a distributed cache as hibernate 2nd level cache all you will need is to configure the cache provider and configure entities to be cached as cacheable, hibernate itself will make use of that provider for caching. e.g. you can see [TayzGrid as Hibernate 2nd level cache](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/hibernate-second-level-cache.html) to configure Tayzgrid with Hibernate. Similarly you can configure any other caching solution.

Despite the fact that Hibernate Second Level Cache provider makes it really easy for you to incorporate 2nd level cache into your Java application, keep in mind that you will get only subset of features of caching solution. However if you make direct API calls to the caching solution through a small programming effort, you would gain all features provided by that solution. Like in case of Tayzgrid direct API calls will get you extra features like bulk operations, groups & tags, sql like searching and write-behind etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of application.

In a modern web application there are a lot sources for caching:

- Optimized images
- Rendered html fragment from the template system
- Composed objects from several database objects
- Select lists, that change not often (countries, tenants, customer addressing)
- Complete search results

If you have a "mostly view" type of application or a high traffic website, it is wise to have a caching layer on top of hibernate. Hibernate is designed for transactional consistency with the database, which has a big performance impact (e.g. by copying the objects). For "mostly view" you don't need strong consistency and you can cache intermediate results, e.g. an HTML fragment.

Using a distributed cache as hibernate second level cache, will cost you a lot resources or even may slow you down. You should evaluate this very carefully. If you have lots of data and database accesses are very costly, may be it is worth it.